# GitHub branch creation duplication?

Tags: github

First, I am new to GitHub.

I know how to create branches in GitHub, but the problem is that when I try to make a new branch, it duplicates the master branch. What happened?

You should look at this: In the master branch I have a main.cpp and a readme.md. Now in the 'libraries' branch I mentioned is when I that I just created has the same contents. As I said it contains .h files part of the repo.

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked here.  You said "As I said it contains .h files part of the repo."  But you didn't say anything about .h files -- probably just a typo but it is very confusing.  What  do you want to do?  What do you mean by "duplicates the main branch"?

Comment: Oh, the repo is (or will be) a C++ program. I want to make an empty branch. And by 'duplicates the main branch', I mean creates the exact same files in the master branch. Besides, it is not confusing to me... Beside, you're asking too many questions for me to handle.

Comment: Do you want to create a directory/folder and add to your project?

Comment: Yes, and make an empty one too.

Comment: Ah okay, then you are not looking to make a branch.  See prothid's answer.

Comment: Yes, but I want to make a branch. I hope this doesn't turn into an argument.

Answer (score 3):

Branching uses the current master branch as a basis for a new branch.  If you want a blank slate, the best practice is to create a new project.

Answer (score 1):

That's how branches are meant to be used. They are supposed to duplicate and then extend the master.

Comment: Yes but I want to start with an empty branch. The branch I want to make will be labeled 'libraries' and it should contain .h files, not a `readme.md` and a `main.cpp`.

Comment: Then what you want to do is include subfolder(s) in the project and add your "libraries" or ".h" files to them. But when you branch: you duplicate the whole project for the purpose of extending this whole project.

Comment: Okay, then. How do you include subfolders? I hope it doesn't involve downloading Git...

Comment: @GavrielFeria Create a subfolder, then issue the command "git add foo" where foo is the actual name of the new subfolder.

Comment: But I don't have Git, and I don't want to download it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really know branch in git? Just have a look at [Git Branching - Basic Branching and Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)

Comment: This is best as a comment, not an answer